# Unichar with specific characters

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to add some specific characters to my

```
unichar rusLetter [] = { 'Ж', 'Й', }
```

I want actually to add all letters from russian alphabet. Using above line of code, i get an error:

```
Character too large for enclosing character literal type
```

Any ideas how to fix that? And maybe there is an easier way to add all letters, not to type all of them.

Thanks

Comment: See the unaccepted answer to the duplicate question for an easy solution (put an `L` in front of each char literal).

Answer (score 1):

the ' literal (single quote) means a char and that is too small to hold the symbols.
In ObjC use an NSString to hold it

```
NSString *rusLetters = @"ЖЙ";

unichar c1 = [rusLetters characterAtIndex:0];
unichar c2 = [rusLetters characterAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. See my comments above about for a simple solution.